# How to Handle the onClick for ListView Without Extending ListActivity?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview populated as follows and it's working.  My issue is with being able to handle the onclick.  I'm not extending the listactivity because all my activities extend a common activity that I use to setup common variables/preferences/etc that are used on all activities.   Is there a way to handle the onclick without extending the listactivity?  and if not, is there a way to import the listactivity (via a class or something)?

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewGhostCams);
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[] {"pen","price","color"},
            new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3}
            );
    populateList();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm new to android / java programming so please be gentle! :-)

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //Your code
        }

    });
```

Comment: This worked!  Thanks.  How do I reference which item was selected?  Is there a variable or anything that's passed to indicate the item clicked?  Thanks again.

Comment: The arguments go parent, rowView, position, and id. So you can take your list of entries you use to setup the adapter and get the item at index of position. Or you can use arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) I think.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you mean onClick on an item? Just use this bit:

> ```
> lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>     @Override             
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
>     view, int position, long id) { 
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can user onItemClickListener

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     ListView listView;
     String[] listPlanet={"mercury","Venus","Mars","Saturn","Neptune"};

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

         listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView));

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,         listPlanet);

         listview.setAdapter(adapter);

         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)      {
                Toast.makeText(getAppicationContext(), listPlanet.get(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }

    });

    }

 }
```